# Getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null In " buttons.html5.min.js" while exporting Custome rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

1. I Am Using Custome Checkboxes To Export Rows From Datatables. I Am Pushing Respected RowsId. The Thing Is My Excel Export Working Perfectly Fine But Copy And CSV Is Not Working

A. On Click, I am calling this function and Passing ID Of respected Row

```
 var rowId=[];
   function checkboxfn(t) {  
      if (t.is(':checked')){
        var index = rowIds.indexOf(t[0]['value']); 
           if (index < 0){
                rowIds.push(t[0]['value']);
            }  
     }else{ 
     //when checkbox is unchecked remove id from rowIds
          var index = rowIds.indexOf(t[0]['value']);
            if (index > -1) {
                rowIds.splice(index, 1);
       }           
      }

  }
```

B. This Is My Excel Code In "buttons.html5.min.js" file Actually its Working Fine

```
for (var f = 0, h = b.body.length; f < h; f++)
   if(rowIds.length != 0){
      var index = rowIds.indexOf(b.body[f][0]);      
      console.log("Excel "+b.body[f][0]);
      if (index < 0){
            //alert("dont export");
      }else{
         b.body[f].splice(0, 1);
          a += e(b.body[f]);
       }  
     }else{
        b.body[f].splice(0, 1);
        a += e(b.body[f]);
      }
    }
```

C. And this is my CSV and Copy the Export code in "buttons.html5.min.js" File but I am getting an error.

```
  for(i=0;i<l.length;i++){
    if(rowIds.length != 0){
       // I AM GETTING ERROR ON BELOW LINE
       var index = rowIds.indexOf(l[i].match(/\d+/)[0]);
       console.log("Copy and CSV "+l[i].match(/\d+/)[0]);
       console.log("Index "+index);
       if (index < 0){
         //alert("dont export");
       }else{
          l[i]=l[i].substr(l[i].indexOf(b.fieldSeparator) + 1);
          temp.push(l[i]);
        }
     }else{
        //removing the row id from the contact before export.
        l[i]=l[i].substr(l[i].indexOf(b.fieldSeparator) + 1);
        temp.push(l[i]);
      }

     }
```

Comment: looks like `l[i]` does _not_ match `/\d+/`!? -> so check what `l[i]` actually is (for each i), check if you have a match before you assign it to `index`

Comment: Thank Sir, Now its Working Perfectly Fine.